# How can I solve these errors and warnings? Also a few questions from this program

Tags: c, vector, menu

I'm making a program that takes data from various rockets (except their first stage engines) and calculates dV with a new, substitute engine.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main () {

int choice;

do {

    printf ("\n1-Register rocket data");
    printf ("\n2-Change already registered data");
    printf ("\n3-Delete rocket data");
    printf ("\n4-Show registered rockets");
    printf ("\n5-Register substitute engine data");
    printf ("\n6-Calculate dV with substitute engine");
    printf ("\n0-End");

    scanf ("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            dV();
        break;

        case 2:
        break;

        case 3:
        break;

        case 4:
        break;

        case 5:
        break;

        case 6:
        break;

        }

    } while(choice != 0);

}


dV () {

    int count, x, i;
    float rockets[] , dV, wetMass, dryMass, Isp;

    printf ("How many rockets will be registered?");
    scanf ("%d", &x);

    while (i == 1) {

        for (count=1; count <= x; count++)


            printf ("\n\nWet Mass(kg): ");
            scanf ("%f", &wetMass);
            fflush (stdin);

            printf ("Dry Mass: ");
            scanf ("%f", &dryMass);
            fflush (stdin);

            printf ("Specific Impulse(Seconds): ");
            scanf ("%f", &Isp);
            fflush (stdin);

            printf ("\nType 1 to add a stage or 0 to end the process: ");
            scanf ("%d", &i);

            dV = (Isp * 9.8 * log(wetMass/dryMass) + dV);

            dV = rockets[x++];


            }

}
```

The error:

error: array size missing in 'rockets' (line 50)

Warnings:

warning: implicit declaration of function 'dV' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration} (line 22)
warning: return type defaults to 'int' (Wimplicit-int) (line 47)

First question: How do I solve these errors and warnings?

Second question: How can I make a vector with user-defined number of elements? The user has to be able to register as many rockets as they want. My plan is to calculate the dV for each rocket and store it in an element of the rocket[] vector after the substitute engine data is provided.

Third question: How can I change the value of an already defined element in a vector?

Fourth question: How can I assign vector elements progressively? By that I mean: First registered rocket data should go to rockets[0], the second to rockets[1], etc.

edit: I forgot to add this after line 55

```
printf ("\ntype 1 to add a stage or 2 to end the process: ");
scanf ("%f", &i);
```

Comment: Declare `float* rockets = malloc(sizeof(float) * x);` after `scanf ("%d", &x);`.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks. But the array size missing error is still there and I got a new error "error: conflicting types for 'rockets'" in the line I added your suggestion in.

Comment: regarding: `line 47` and `line 50` and `line 55`   Depending on several factors, which lines are those?  Please include a comment on each of those lines of interest.

Comment: Note: indentation means NOTHING to the compiler.  indentation is for us humans to read the code.  If you want a block of lines to be associated with a specific control statement (like `for()` or `while()` or `if()` Then that block of lines must be surrounded by a '{' and a '}'

Comment: do NOT have a local variable with the same name (I.E. dV) as the enclosing function.  At best, it is confusing to the human reader.  At worst, the compiler will think those are 'recursive' calls

Comment: regarding: `int count, x, i;` and `while (i == 1) {`  Since the variable `i` was not initialized, it contains what ever trash was in memory at its' location. And since the variable 'i' can contain any value from -(2^^31)-1 to `(2^^31) It is highly probable that it does NOT contain 1

Comment: regarding: `fflush (stdin);`  The C language standard specifically states that this results in undefined behavior (function: `fflush()` is for output streams only)  suggest: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}`

Comment: regarding: `Isp * 9.8`   The variable `Isp` is a `float` while the literal: `9.8` is a `double` This can result in data corruption.  Suggest: `Isp * 9.8f`  Note the trailing `f` which makes the literal a `float`

Comment: regarding: `float rockets[] , dV, wetMass, dryMass, Isp;` and `dV = (Isp * 9.8 * log(wetMass/dryMass) + dV);` The variable `dV` is not initialized, so contains what every trash was in memory at its' address.  Using a uninitalized variable for input results in undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `for (count=1; count <= x; count++)` and `dV = rockets[x++];` will result in the loop never ending as the (should be fixed value) 'x' is moving as fast as the index value `count`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note:other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: Since your code has so many quirks and errors, I suggest to learn some basic C before going on. Divide your task into smaller tasks, learn and **understand** each of them.

Answer (score 0):

To remove errors and warnings, do changes as below i.e. create float array of rockets after you fetched value of x and initialize i by 1 before using it in while and add void in return type of dV function if any return value not needed.

```
void dV () {

    int count, x, i;
    float  dV, wetMass, dryMass, Isp;

    printf ("How many rockets will be registered?");
    scanf ("%d", &x);

    float rockets[x];

    i=1;

    while (i == 1) {
.
.
}
```

Answer to your second question : either make rockets as global array or return it to main through dV function.